# File Not Found Error reading SD Card

Tags: android, xml, sd-card

I'm writing an airplane simulator program and want the user to be able create model files seperately using XML.  Then, in the app they can select which model (XML file) to load.  I have the XML files in a subdirectory on my SD card and can read it with my BLU phone but not my Motorola Photon II.  With the Motorola I get a file not found when initializing the input stream. I have the following code...

In the Manifest I have set read external storage permission...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here's the code to open the XML file...

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SimFiles/Vehicles/" + "myModel.xml");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

It's pretty straight forward. So, why on one and not the other?  Is it a permissions thing- one more strict than the other?  Thanks.

Comment: LogCat?  I think it has to do with the fact that different devices has different sdcard names in different android versions

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct.  I think Motorola device maps part of internal storage to external storage???  When I plug devices in Windows list two subdirectories.  One named Phone and the other SD Card.  I put my XML files in the latter.  But after sleuthing by listing contents of external storage I found that the Motorola external storage is really the Phone directory.  Moving my XML file there fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SimFiles/Vehicles/" + "myModel.xml");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```